# Selecting two things in linq one from inner json array and one from outer json array

Tags: c#, json, linq

So I have a JSON object that looks like this

```
{
  "someOtherData": "notImportant",
  "outerlist": [
    {
      "somedata": 1504461600,
      "innerList": [
        {
          "data1": 801,
          "data2": "blah",
          "innerDataNeeded": "the inner list data needed"
        }
      ],
      "outerDataNeeded": "outer Data Needed"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was trying to write a linq query to return both the `innerDataNeeded` and the `outerDataNeeded`

So I wrote two to get both but I'm not sure how to connect them together and get the desired result with one query.

current code is like so

```
var listOfInnerData = from listItem in jsonObject["outerList"] from innerJsonList in listItem["innerList"] select (string) innerJsonList["innerDataNeeded"];
var listOfOuterData = from listItem in jsonObject["outerList"] select (string)listItem["outerDataNeeded"];
```

Comment: Convert your json to concrete classes, so you can work on it easier. http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options to extract the `innerDataNeeded` and `outerDataNeeded`, joined together in groups, using LINQ-to-JSON.

Firstly, you could use nested `from` statements to perform a [`SelectMany()`](https://dzone.com/articles/selectmany-probably-the-most-p) on the inner list to generate a single, flat list of joined pairs:

```
var query = from outerItem in jsonObject.SelectTokens("outerlist[*]")
            let outerData = outerItem["outerDataNeeded"]
            from innerData in outerItem.SelectTokens("innerList[*].innerDataNeeded")
            select new { OuterData = (string)outerData, InnerData = (string)innerData };

var listOfData = query.ToList();
```

Resulting in

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "OuterData": "outer Data Needed",
>     "InnerData": "the inner list data needed"
>   }
> ]
> ```

Secondly, if there is a possibility that the `innerList` array might be missing or empty and you still want to get the corresponding outer data values, you can sub in a default value using [`DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var query = from outerItem in jsonObject.SelectTokens("outerlist[*]")
            let outerData = outerItem["outerDataNeeded"]
            from innerData in outerItem.SelectTokens("innerList[*].innerDataNeeded").DefaultIfEmpty(JValue.CreateNull())
            select new { OuterData = (string)outerData, InnerData = (string)innerData };

var listOfData = query.ToList();
```

Finally, if you would prefer your list of results to be structured as outer an inner collections, you can use a nested LINQ query as follows:

```
var query = from outerItem in jsonObject.SelectTokens("outerlist[*]")
            select new 
            {
                OuterData = (string)outerItem["outerDataNeeded"], 
                InnerData = outerItem.SelectTokens("innerList[*].innerDataNeeded").Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray() 
            };

var listOfData = query.ToList();
```

Which results in:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "OuterData": "outer Data Needed",
>     "InnerData": [
>       "the inner list data needed"
>     ]
>   }
> ]
> ```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JPat2P) showing these three options.

Notes -

- The method [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) enables selection of multiple tokens using [JSONPath query syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).  In this syntax, the `[*]` operator is a wildcard that matches all array members.  Using `SelectTokens()` avoids the need for nested `from`/`select` queries at each level of the `JToken` hierarchy.
- If certain properties are missing, `SelectTokens()` will simply not enumerate over anything, whereas nested `from`/`select` will throw null reference exceptions unless `null` is checked for and skipped.
- Pasting your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/ or using [Paste JSON As Classes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc/) to generate concrete types for your JSON, then deserializing to those types and querying the result, is another option to consider.